# Mysql_query() expects parameter to be mysqli/string

Tags: php, mysql, string

I'm sure this is a very simple problem, but since I just started learning PHP it makes absolutely no sense to me. I hope you guys could give me a hint to what I'm missing.

I'm getting these errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in advies.php on line 27

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in advies.php on line 33
Error:
```

On this PHP code:

```
   <?php
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//Connect to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

mysql_select_db("database_name");

//Update data in database
if ($_POST["soort"]='HTK')
{
mysqli_query ($dbhandle, "UPDATE Computers
SET Totaal_P=100
WHERE ProductName='iPad air 16GB Wi-Fi'");
}



//Error if update failed.
if (!mysql_query($dbhandle))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

//Close database connection.
mysql_close($dbhandle)
?>
```

Comment: Why did you use `mysql_connect` with `mysqli_query`? `mysql` and `mysqli` are different.

Comment: Since you started with learning PHP/MySQL it would be better not to use the deprecated mysql_* functions. Use mysqli or PDO instead right from the start. Use prepared statements and bind your input values to parameters to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple problems here. To start you're using deprecated mysql functions. Use mysqli instead. Secondly(where the errors are coming from) mysql expects the first parameter to be the query, not the link(error 2). and mysqli expects a mysqli link for the first parameter, not mysql(error 1).

Check out the documentations for [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and change the code to use mysqli this way.